C# FileInfo.Exists always returns false for a shared network path in a Windows service
Question:
I am using the FileInfo.Exists method in C# to check whether a file exists on a shared network location. However, the method always returns false, even though the file is present at the specified path. The path is correct, and I can access the file manually.
Additionally, I am running my application as a Windows service. I suspect the issue might be related to the service's permissions or its ability to access network paths, but I’m not sure how to resolve this.
Here’s the code I’m using:
public string url
{
    get { return URL; }
    set
    {
        connected = false;
        URL = value;
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(URL);
        logger.Debug("File name: " + fi.FullName + " Exist: " + fi.Exists);
        if (fi.Exists && fi.Extension == ".csv")
        {
            connected = true;
            logger.Debug("Connected to " + URL);
            numberofretries = 0;
            dataTable = ConvertCsvToDataTable(URL);
            logger.Debug("Converted CSV to DataTable");
        }
    }
}


File paths aren't URLs. If you use a URL it's no wonder FileInfo won't work. It's also a bad idea to use a string property to do actual heavy work like loading and parsing a CSV file. That's the job of a function, perhaps even an asynchronous function.

Another possibility is that while the path is valid, the service account has no permission to read that file. Accounts like Local Service, Network Service or (shudder) Local System are local so if you try to run your service with them, the connection to the remote server is done using the computer's account. You'll have to use a domain account (one with minimal privileges) to connect to other machines

Here the URL is the path of the File present '////Servername//Foldername//'. Could you please explain the second possibilty and to resolve that? @Panagiotis Kanavos

That's neither a Windows or Linux path. \\servername\foldername is a Windows path. Only backslashes need escaping. You can avoid escaping altogether if you use verbatim strings, ie @"\\servername\foldername" in code. If you load the path from a file or configuration you don't need to escape anything either.

There are a few things you'll want to troubleshoot, but first; If I may humbly suggest a syntax tweak:
public string path
{
   get { return _path; }
   set
   {
        connected = false;
        _path = value;

       try
       {
            if (!File.Exists(_path))
            {
                logger.Debug($"File does not exist: {_path}");
                return;
            }

            if (Path.GetExtension(_path) != ".csv")
            {
                logger.Debug($"File is not correctly formatted: {_path}");
                return;
            }

            logger.Debug($"File Found! Converting CSV to DataTable...");
            connected = true;
            numberofretries = 0; // would recommend "numRetries" as this follows camelCase
            dataTable = ConvertCsvToDataTable(_path);
            logger.Debug("Conversion complete.");
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
        {
            logger.Debug($"Access denied: {uae.Message}");
        }
    }
}

Here I have added initial logging using System.IO.File.Exists and System.IO.Path.GetExtension to distinguish between !fi.Exists and fi.Extension != ".csv" events in the case that the files are being found, but the format isn't correct. I put everything within a try/catch statement looking to catch an UnauthorizedAccessException which should throw if attempting to access something you lack permissions for. I've also renamed url and URL to path and _path respectively to one, abide by naming conventions, but more importantly to show that this is a path and not a URL.
Make sure your input path is the correct format. Strings are a little picky when it comes to backslashes \. I would recommend using a verbatim string which allows backslashes without issue. You can do this by putting @ at the front of your strings. ex: @"\\ServerName\SharedFolder\data.csv"
Now that the program code is optimized, you should easily be able to tell what the issue is. You mentioned you suspect is has something to do with permissions because it's running as a Windows service- from what I'm reading, you should be able to go to the start menu, open Services, find the program, right click and change the permissions in properties. If you're running it on a different user, make sure that user has permissions.
Best of luck!

numRetries is bad.

This whole ordeal wouldn't get past my review. The mountain of side-effects, the heavy work including file I/O ... in a setter. That would be highly surprising to any client I would know. Not to speak about the unclear state in the error case.

I am tweaking their syntax to help diagnose the issue, not rewriting their program. They use FileInfo which is part of System.IO in their original snippet. If you have a problem with how they use setters, talk to them. "unclear state in the error case" is laughable considering the specific UnauthorizedAccessException is being caught. Instead of trying to find issues with other people's answers, write your own.

@NathanKirby insulting the experienced people that explain the problems in your code only attracts downvotes. This code doesn't help at all  and hides the actual problem because debug messages are typically filtered. If the file is missing, an exception will be thrown anyway. You can use catch(Exception ex){ logger.LogError(ex,"Oops");throw;} to log the full exception.

this is my first time on this website, why is it so ****ing toxic?? I was just trying to help. I am not "insulting" anyone. I am experienced as well, and like I mentioned, I am not rewriting his program, I am just trying to make it easier for him to diagnose the issue.
